# Adding gradient fades to content that overflows a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. I'm trying to add a gradient fade on content that overflows a , as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/6k3vV/
2. On the div I have a set height of 200 pixels
3. I want to optionally show the fade depending on whether or not the content actually overflows the 200px

Things work ok if I have all the content/resources already loaded:

Something like `<h1>Hello World</h1>` will work fine and I can calculate the height that that would occupy
  if I insert it into the document

However, if I have something like `<h1>Hello World</h1><img src=".." />` it will not work as I cannot reliably 
  determine the height the contents would occupy until the image itself is loaded.

I'm trying to add this functionality on a comments page where I inject each comment into a wrapping div and optionally
display the gradient fade.  The current solution that I am thinking of is checking for and  tag and attaching an onload
event handler that will calculate the height after the image loads.

is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a set height, it's easy. On doc load (or an event), just check the height of each "section" and append a div w/ the class fadeout if that height is greater than 200.

[Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/6k3vV/307/)

I would recommend adding a class to your `<section>` element rather than using that element as a whole selector.

You may want to play around with using the `height` of `.fadeout` as a `%` rather than `em`